# Is it possible to change the thickness of the line drawn by "quadraticCurveTo" as you go along the curve?

Tags: javascript, canvas, drawing, pad

I have a drawing pad, and I use quadraticCurveTo to make all of the lines and curves, and I want the line to get thinner when you move the mouse faster. However if I just do something like calculate the velocity of the pen and have that alter the thickness of the curves, then each curve is a different thickness, and the thickness doesn't change smoothly. Is there another way to do this?

In other words - can quadraticCurveTo only draw a curve at a set thickness, and not change the thickness throughout the curve?

If yes, can you think of another way I can change the thickness of the line?

Here is a jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/y24su/

Here is the main part of the code that draws the curves -

```
if (isMouseDown){
                        ++i;
                        X[i] = e.pageX;
                        Y[i] = e.pageY;
                               var x1 = X[i-2];
                               var y1 = Y[i-2];
                               var x2 = X[i-1];
                               var y2 = Y[i-1];
                               var x3 = X[i];
                               var y3 = Y[i];
                               var mid1x = (x1 + x2)/2;
                               var mid1y = (y1 + y2)/2;
                               var mid2x = (x2 + x3)/2;
                               var mid2y = (y2 + y3)/2;

                                var distance = Math.pow((Math.pow(mid2x-x2,2) + Math.pow(mid2y-y2,2)),2) + Math.pow((Math.pow(x2-mid1x,2) + Math.pow(y2-mid1y,2)),2);
                                var velocity = distance/2;
                              if(i>1)
                              {
                                  if (velocity<1)
                                  { drawQuadraticThreePoints("black", 10,  mid1x, mid1y, x2, y2, mid2x, mid2y);
                                  }
                                  else
                                  { drawQuadraticThreePoints("black", 10/velocity,  mid1x, mid1y, x2, y2, mid2x, mid2y);
                                  }
                              }
                          } 


function drawQuadraticThreePoints (color, thickness, x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3) {
  context.strokeStyle = color;
  context.lineWidth   = thickness;

  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(x1,y1);
  context.quadraticCurveTo(x2,y2,x3,y3);
  context.stroke();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You only get 1 context.lineWidth setting for each context.beginPath.**

**That means your context.quadraticCurveTo can only have 1 linewidth.**

To get a variable width line without the "chunky" width changes, you must break your quadratic curves into many smaller line-segments.

With many line-segements you can gradually change the line width between each segment.

The following function calculates xy points along a quadratic curve.

```
function getQuadraticBezierXYatT(startPt,controlPt,endPt,T) {
    var x = Math.pow(1-T,2) * startPt.x + 2 * (1-T) * T * controlPt.x + Math.pow(T,2) * endPt.x; 
    var y = Math.pow(1-T,2) * startPt.y + 2 * (1-T) * T * controlPt.y + Math.pow(T,2) * endPt.y; 
    return( {x:x,y:y} );
}
```

These are the inputs to the function:

- startPt, controlPt, endPt are objects: eg. { x:10, y:20 }
- T is an interval along the curve from 0.00 to 1.00
- T==0.00 at the start of the line
- T==1.00 at the end of the line

The rule of 1 lineWidth per beginPath still applies, but drawing multiple line segments per curve gives you more beginPaths with which to gradually adjust your lineWidth.

Comment: So basically I'd replace "drawQuadraticThreePoints" with your function, and that will give me all of the x and y points, and then I specify, for instance, t==0 to t==.1, get the x and y points for those 2 values, and draw the line? and then do the same for t==.1 to t==.2, etc.

Comment: Oh wait I think I understand - I use this function over and over, and get the points at different values of t, and then draw the lines?

Comment: Yes,  (1) break each curve into x,y points--T=0.00, T=0.10, ..., T=1.00. (2) Draw each line segment along the curve with gradually changing context.lineWidth--beginpath; moveTo; lineTo; lineWidth; stroke;  Plotting more points along the curve == a smoother curve and smoother linewidth transition.

Comment: One more thought. Set the lineJoin to `round` for a better looking transition between line segments: ctx.lineJoin = "round";  Good luck with your project!